how can i add genre meta tag in Next JS 13
i want add genre meta in my project but when I use other in metas for creat this my export html I get bellow tag
meta name="genre" content="Commodity prices"/>

but its wrong I wand get this tag
<meta name="genre" itemprop="genre" content="Commodity prices">

my code:
other: {
      genre: 'Commodity prices',
    },

I think in this version we can't add itemprop in metas
